# Multiply values from mixed Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I've got a `String[] formelHolder` in which there are `Strings` ("words" and numbers *like H2O*) from an UI source (`input` here). For each of the "words" I get an value from a database which is added into the `double[] massHolder` `[double[]]`. Now I want to multiply the doubles in `massHolder[k-1]` with the numbers from the `formelHolder[k]` so for example, the value from *H* in `massHolder` will be multiplied with the *2* from `formelHolder`.
I've tried this so far:

```
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            double masse = 0.0;
            String formel = textFieldFormel.getText();
            String[] formelHolder = formel.split("(?=[A-Z0-9])");
            double[] massHolder = new double[formelHolder.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < formelHolder.length; i++){
                System.out.println("formelHolder[i]: i="+i+ formelHolder[i]);
                if (formelHolder[i].equals("2")){
                } else {
                    massHolder[i] = Double.parseDouble(dbhandler.getMass(formelHolder[i]));
                    System.out.println("i: "+ i+ " FormelHolder: "+formelHolder[i] +" Masse: "+massHolder[i]);

                    for (int k = 0; k<formelHolder.length; k++){
                        if (formelHolder[k].equals("2")){
                            masse = masse + massHolder[k-1]*Double.parseDouble(formelHolder[k]);
                        } else { 
                            masse = masse + massHolder[k];
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("Finally: "+masse);


                }
            }
        }
    });
```

resulting in, for example in  the case of *HH2* with massHolder for *H = 1.01* ---> abc = 4.04 instead of abc = 3.03

Content of formelHolder will be (for the example HH2 which should result in 3.03 instead of 4.04):

```
formelHolder[1] = H
formelHolder[2] = H
formelHolder[3] = 2

massHolder[1] = 1.01
massHolder[2] = 1.01
massHolder[3] -> empty [due to being a number in formelHolder]
```

Current code is, as given in your awnser:

```
for (int k = 0; k<formelHolder.length-1; k++){
                        if (formelHolder[k].matches("\\d+(.\\d+)?")){
                            double masseHolder = Double.parseDouble(formelHolder[k]);
                            masse += massHolder[k-1]*(masseHolder-1);
                        } else { 
                            masse += massHolder[k];
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Could you show us content of `dArray` and `sArray` ? And `formelHolder` ?

Comment: You do realise an empty `else {}` clause can be removed?

Comment: Also, note that using a debugger you could understand what's going on pretty easily.

Comment: `StringArray` and `doubleArray` are not types I'm familiar with.  Are these some sort of wrapper class you wrote?

Comment: @azurefrog If so, then indexing wouldn't be applicable.

Comment: so formelHolder == sArray.

Comment: @Zi1mann  Why is H2O a "number"???

Comment: @laune Yeah, I'm finding the OP's pseudocode style confusing.

Comment: @Zi1mann Can you please post your actual code?  It would be much easier to read and understand what you're actually doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, but see below.

```
double abc = 0.0;
for (int k = 0; k < formelHolder.length - 1; k++){

   if (formelHolder[k].matches("\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")){
      double f = Double.parseDouble(formelHolder[k]);
      abc += massHolder[k-1]*(f-1);
   } else {
      abc += massHolder[k];
   }
}
```

I simply add the numeric values for all non-numeric entries. For a numeric entry, I convert the factor subtract one (!) and multiply with the numeric value at the preceding index.

This assumes that the two arrays are used in parallel. If massHolder does not contain fillers (null or 0) for numeric values in formelHolder, the index values for formelHolder must be carried in another variable and incremented explicitly whenever a value is taken from that array.

There are a few possible hiccups.

```
sArray = new formelHolder[]{ "22", ... }
```

First entry may not be numeric.

```
sArray = new formelHolder[]{ "H", "3", "2",...}
```

There may not be two numbers in a row.

**Edit** Merged with OP's code

```
public static void compute( String formula, double[] values ){
    double masse = 0.0;
    String[] formulaHolder = formula.split("(?=[A-Z0-9])");
    double[] massHolder = new double[formulaHolder.length];

    for (int k = 0; k < formulaHolder.length; k++){
        String form = formulaHolder[k];
        if (form.matches("\\d+")){
            double f = Double.parseDouble(form);
             masse += massHolder[k-1]*(f-1);
        } else {
             massHolder[k] = values[k]; // get the value from the db
             masse += massHolder[k];
        }
    }
    System.out.println( masse );
}
```

Comment: Thanks works but I updated my code to the actual one Im using resulting in your solution not being adequate anymore but Im going to delete the question anyways because I would have to rename all the variables. Thx

Comment: Caught up with the changes to the actual names. Next time post the right thing please. It just saves time and effort.

Comment: Well, just noticed its not working for inputs like "H2H" - any suggestions? Would be nice even though you helped alot already.

Comment: OK, but what *is* your current code? Your Q version, my A version? - You might add the current version at the end of your Q.

Comment: Yes thats the case, but in a testclass applying the very same split it works perfectly fine: `public static void main(String[] args) {
  String s = "HeFNeO2H3Be1HHH";
  String[] r = s.split("(?=[A-Z0-9])");
  for (int i = 0; i<r.length; i++){
   System.out.println(""+r[i]);
  }` resulting in: `Ne
O
2
H
3
Be
1
H
H
H`

Comment: If you dont find a solution now dont worry ill ask my teacher tomorrow showing him the actual code. Thanks anyways you helped alot.

Comment: There are molecules where an atom occurs more than 9 times. Then the split with the current regex will not work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92417/discussion-between-zi1mann-and-laune).

Comment: This regex fixes the >9 atoms: "(?=[A-Z])|(?<![0-9])(?=[0-9])", i.e. split before an upper case letter and a digit that is not following a digit.

Comment: Nice, ill try when back home but this wont solve the "H2HH" problem

Comment: Also "H2HH" works with the method I've posted. Clearly, we are not in sync, possibly due to the DB access. I'd suggest a different approach for this, as the parallel array is rather shaky: Use a `Map<String,Double>` for caching the atom masses!

Comment: Perfect its working now I really appreciate your help. Impressed that you stayed with me! :) When it comes down to improving the code you have to know its a school project so the primary target is to get it running in an *acceptable* way. Maybe later Ill work on it. Thanks again!